# How do I add a css class to an <li> element that contains a given ID using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an active class to the `<li>` that an ID is in, for example:

```
<li><a href="" id="foo">text</a></li>
```

How can I add a class to the `<li>` that `#foo` is in?

Comment: This question shows a major lack of any research

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#foo').parent('li').addClass("yourclass")
```

Comment: wouldnt that target the li INSIDE of the #foo element?

Comment: @jake you edited your question while I was typing. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#foo").closest("li").addClass("bar");
```

If your `<a>` tag might be wrapped in other elements, and not a direct child of `<li>`, `parent('li')` will not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/PMfVK/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div><a id="foo">Foo</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a id="bar">Bar</a></div></li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
$("#foo").closest("li").addClass("foo"); // this will correctly grab the li
$("#bar").parent("li").addClass("bar");​  // this will grab nothing
```

Comment: `closest` will be the preferred method if your `a` might be wrapped in other elements like so: `<li><div><a ...>text</a></div></li>`

Comment: If the element with the ID has li elements within it, then closest will select them.

Comment: @Adam `closest` only walks UP the DOM. It ignores any child nodes completely.

Comment: @Adam: Well naturally they're green. Everything inside the outer `li` is going to be green. Use a border in the style, and you'll see that only the outer `li` was selected. http://jsfiddle.net/BeWtY/1/

Comment: @Shmiddity and user1600680: You are right. Good point. I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @user1600680 Yes. Sorry about that. I realized the flaw in my jsfiddle a few seconds after I posted my comment and deleted it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").has("#foo").addClass("yourclass")
```

Comment: *Because `:has()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:has()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").has(selector/DOMElement)` instead* ( http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/#notes-0 )

Comment: I did not check that it works, but if you say so, I updated my code.

Comment: I believe this will result in more DOM walking over-all. While it may work, the performance might become noticeably worse.

Answer (score 0):

First select the element with the ID `foo` using [the ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Then, use [`.parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select the `<li>` parent of that element. Use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to ensure that only the nearest parent is found. Finally, use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add the class to the `<li>` element.

Since we are using parent *s*  even if the element with the `foo` ID is nested several elements below the `<li>` it will still be selected.

```
$("#foo").parents("li").eq(0).addClass("bar");​​
```

[See my example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/7SR3A/)

Comment: *Because `:eq()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:eq()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index)` instead* ( http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#notes-0 )

Comment: True. I updated the code to use .eq

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[id]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ2D4/)